# How can I fill a hole in masonry so I can redrill?

Tags: drill

I am looking to install a folding clothesline that is bolted on the outer wall of the house.

To do that I will need to drill several holes into the brick wall, but as I have never drilled anything in my life, I am somewhat planning ahead for my mistakes.

If I was to make a mistake and drilled on a slight angle, is there a way to seal the hole and be able to re-drill on the same/similar spot?

Answer (score 4):

Unless you are considerably more than "on a slight angle", you are unlikely to have a problem. If you are slightly more out, the screw should still hold the clothesline, just the screw head won't sit as neat on the surface.

Take your time, let the drill do the work, and don't force it.

Answer (score 1):

Measure twice, drill once?
Rapid set mortar will get you out of trouble.
Be sure you have a masonry anchor ready for after you drill.

Comment: I'm not worried about the positioning of the holes but the angle the hole was drilled.